# The King's new dress

Tags: pattern, poetry, anagram

The King has come to me at once 
And ordered that I make a suit

> "The suit should have a lot of folds 
>   Contain a lot of metal discs 
>   Please color it by using paint 
>   Then decorate with flower leaves 
>   And please adhere a crown with tape"

Five items was I missing though 
Replaced them with what I could find 
King took the suit, and, going out, 
Looked like the (?) man in town.

Comment: Unique! I like it.

Comment: I’m just going to guess “Looked like the ‘old, foolish’ man of town” in here just because that sounds like a ridiculous outfit already.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The suit should have a lot of folds

> pleats

Contain a lot of metal discs

> plates

Please color it by using paint

> pastel (pointed out by Darrel Hoffman in the comments)

Then decorate with flower leaves

> petals

And please adhere a crown with tape

> staple

Five items was I missing though
Replaced them with what I could find

> The narrator was out of tape so they used staples, etc. (from Darrel Hoffman)

King took the suit, and, going out,
Looked like the (?) man in town.

> palest

Comment: I imagine that it might use rot13(cnfgry) colors...

Comment: I think the "missing/replaced" lines simply refer to having to improvise, which is why we have rot13(cnfgry vafgrnq bs cnvag, crgnyf vafgrnq bs yrnirf, fgncyr vafgrnq bs gncr, rgp.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Oh, I see now. Thanks! (Also, apparently rot13(cnyrg) doesn't mean what I had thought it meant!)